# Is there a way in React to test whether or not a Functional Component calls a particular custom hook?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, tdd, react-functional-component, react-custom-hooks

```
describe("UI Logic", () => {
    it("Uses useEmailMultiSelectCustomHook", () => {
        const component = render(<EmailMultiSelectCombobox/>);
        const hook = jest.mock("./useEmailMultiSelectCombobox", () => ({
            useEmailMuliSelect: () => {
                return {
                    initialConditions: ["test", "test1", "test2"]
                }
            }
        }));
        
        const hookTest = renderHook(useEmailMultiSelectCombobox);
        expect(hookTest).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    });
})
```

```
export const EmailMultiSelectCombobox = () => {
    const { initialConditions } = useEmailMultiSelectCombobox();
    
    
    return (
        <>
            {/*<MultiSelectCombobox initialConditions={} handleSelectionChange={}/>*/}
        </>
    )
};
```

```
export const useEmailMultiSelectCombobox = () => {
    const [initialConditions, setInitialConditions] = useState<Array<string>>([]);
    
    
    return { initialConditions };

}
```

So, I have a superrrr basic setup here. All I'm trying to do is test whether or not the hook was called/initialized from the component that I want to use the custom hook. The idea here is to be able to truly unit test a custom hook apart from unit testing a view. Most things I've seen really involve an integration test with a component view layer and a component logic layer being tested together, using the user-events library that comes with the testing library.

Comment: A minor comment but I think you might be mocking the hook too late. You are mocking it after rendering, which could cause issues.

Answer (score 0):

I only have questionable answers for you which aren't really great in production, but for testing - could be acceptable?

Here's some arcane knowledge that might help. Keep in mind this is a fairly cursed abuse of power, but it might work for your purposes.

**Option 1**

All functions in JavaScript have a secret way to extract the code that was used to make them. Here's an example:

```js
function MyComponent({ id, ...props }) {
   const [clicked, setClicked] = useState(false);
   return <div onClick={setClicked.bind(this,true)} id={id} {...props}>Hello, world</div>;
}

console.log({ usesState: MyComponent.toString().includes("useState"));
```

There are some nuances here. For example: if your component uses `styled-components` or really any kind of composition (like `connect()` with redux) this might not work. But if the component is pure, it should meet your needs.

I want to emphasize this is a fairly questionable use of `function.toString()`.

**Option 2**

Also a bad idea, but you could have your hook in question set some test flag somewhere and then check for the presence of it.

```js
function useMyHook() {
   window.useMyHookTriggered = true;
}

if (window.useMyHookTriggered) {
   // Hook was used
}
```

This is not great because it pollutes the public namespace. But again, it'd work.

**Option 3**

Your hook could emit an event. This solution, I don't hate. Still kinda pollutes things, but in a sane way.

```js
function useMyHook() {
   window.dispatchEvent(new Event("useMyHookInvoked"));
}

// The test
window.addeventlistener("useMyHookInvoked", () => {
   assert(true);
})
```